# getting error while displaying image from path in android

Tags: android, storage, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I have arrayList of imagepaths from gallary,I am trying to display an image from path into an imageView,but I got exception

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Facebook/FB_IMG_1423397140297.jpg|: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

My code is as below, can anyone please tell me where is the mistake in that,

**code**

```
public class AndroidCustomGalleryActivity extends Activity {
    private int count;
    private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
    private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
    private String[] arrPath;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_images);

        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                null, orderBy);
        int image_column_index = imagecursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
        this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
        this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
        this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
        }
        GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
        imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        imagecursor.close();

        final Button selectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        selectBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
                int cnt = 0;
                String selectImages = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                        cnt++;
                        selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";

                        Const.my_images.add(selectImages);

                        System.out.println("IMAGES " + Const.my_images);

                    }
                }
                if (cnt == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please select at least one image",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "You've selected Total " + cnt + " image(s).",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);

                    Intent i = new Intent(AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this,
                            HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.raw, null);
                holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.checkbox.setId(position);
            holder.imageview.setId(position);
            holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    int id = cb.getId();
                    if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                        cb.setChecked(false);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                    } else {
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int id = v.getId();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + arrPath[id]),
                            "image/*");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
            holder.id = position;
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageview;
        CheckBox checkbox;
        int id;
    }


}
```

Comment: Show code of Const.my_images.get(0) method

Comment: Can you check this path /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Facebook/FB_IMG_1423397140297.jpg in your device. Which is existing or not?

Comment: @Amsheer-see my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

path which you providing does not contain directory folder, check whether you make directory already or not...

check img1.getAbsolutePath() ...

to get image.......

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                    PHOTO_FROM_GALLERY);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_FROM_GALLERY_KITKAT);
        }



 *****in onActivityResult*****

   if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
        String filePath = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        Uri originalUri = null;
          if (requestCode == PHOTO_FROM_GALLERY) {
            originalUri = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(originalUri,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close(); 
        } else if (requestCode == PHOTO_FROM_GALLERY_KITKAT) {
            originalUri = data.getData();
            int takeFlags = data.getFlags()
                    & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            getActivity().getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(originalUri, takeFlags);
            filePath = getPath(getActivity(), originalUri); 
        }
    }
```

*******************outside onActivityResult*************

```
   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) {
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                    Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
                                   String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {column};

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri
            .getAuthority());
}
```

Comment: Hello,Thanks for quick response,i didnt have made any directory,i directly taking gallary image path.

Comment: okk.....are you trying to get profile pics or any shared pics....like whatsapp profile pic or fb profile pic...?????

Comment: getting this in img1.getAbsolutePath() ...04-07 15:26:44.010: I/System.out(6756): ===========my absolute -path============/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Facebook/FB_IMG_1423397140297.jpg|

Comment: actually i am getting paths of all selected images from gallary but while setting it to imageView,i got exception

Comment: Thanks for code,But i am confused...can you provide only usable code,Or guide where to change in mine.

Comment: i edit my code according to you ...this is only pick image from gallery ..both for prior to kitakat and later ...

Comment: this is code for picking image from gallary (which doesnt needed),I just want how too display image from a path into imageView.

Comment: if you get your path from gallery then try this way to get path...filepath in my code give you path of the image and after getting path you decode that path...

Comment: your code is make me too confuse to use..! so many variables not found..!can you please help me in my code?

Comment: int PHOTO_FROM_GALLERY_KITKAT=1;
int PHOTO_FROM_GALLERY=2;

and all other variables are declared ...just check out edited code ...

Comment: in your code you didn't mention from where u get the path..??

Comment: At this place,I am aving paths..  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                        cnt++;
                        selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";

                        Const.my_images.add(selectImages);

                        System.out.println("IMAGES " + Const.my_images);

                    }
                }